# Modify parent element style

Tags: html, css

My blog simulates a terminal screen, so normal text is green and links are in red with a red background when the mouse is over. Since I use a monospaced font throughout the blog, `<code>` is styled to have a green background to differentiate from regular text. Likewise, `<code>` inside `<a>` has a red background that turns darker when the mouse is over. See [this test page](http://www.cabaladada.org/testing/) for a live version.

Here is the CSS ([complete file here](http://www.cabaladada.org/testing/style.css)) for `<a>` tags:

```
a {
  color:#CD0000;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: background-color .6s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .6s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: background-color .6s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -o-transition: background-color .6s; /* Opera */
}

a:hover {
  background-color:#440000;
}
```

And for `<code>` tags inside `<a>` tags:

```
a code {
  /* Only apply this to code that is a hyperlink */
  color: #161616;
  background-color: #CD0000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 2px 0px 2px;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: background-color .6s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .6s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: background-color .6s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -o-transition: background-color .6s; /* Opera */
}

a code:hover {
  background-color:#440000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 2px 0px 2px;
}
```

The problem is that when I mouse over a link such as `<a href='#'><code>long code</code></a>`, the backgrounds of both the `<code>` and the `<a>` tags are transformed. Here are two images that illustrate this. In the first image, I managed to put the pointer of the mouse only over the `<a>` element. In the second, the mouse is over the `<code>` element:

[image: Mouse is over the <a> element]
[image: Mouse is now over the <code> element]

Is there a way to style `<code>` links differently from normal links? Thank you in advance.

Comment: And how do you want it to look?

Comment: I want the `<code>` link to have the background transformed when the mouse is over. But only the `<code>` background, and not both the `<code>` and `<a>` backgrounds, as of now.

Comment: But they're the same color when hovered..?

Comment: `<a>` indeed has a background when hovered, and that is expected for regular text, but I want to turn it off when it is surrounding `<code>`.

Comment: It doesn't. The background for `<code>` has a 5px round border. The background for regular `<a>` isn't rounded. If you zoom in, it is possible to see that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37407/discussion-between-itay-and-rberaldo)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `contains()` selector, which is no longer part of the [css3 selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors)

To achieve this, you will want to look at either a js framework solution, like [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)  in jquery or a dynamic css solution, such as [less](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: You mean like `<a class="code-inside"><code>...`  That would work, but since that would require some parsing to catch these cases on output (assuming it should stay dynamic and  OP doesn't want to insert the class by hand), this would likely be same amount of work as suggested solutions. I'm not seeing how to do it in `less`, actually. Maybe jquery is the way to go after all.